# Find last updated record where other column has a specific value and status

Tags: sql-server, datetime, status

I have the following:

```
Corp_ID   ExpireDate  RecordUpdateDate       Status    State
100       2013/08/02  2013-04-02  00:00:00   Active     CO
100       2013/08/05  2013-08-02  00:00:00   Active     CO
100       2013/08/26  2013-08-05  00:00:00   Closed     NV
100       2013/10/24  2013-08-26  00:00:00   Active     CO   <<<------
100       2013/11/14  2013-10-24  00:00:00   Active     NV
100       12/31/9999  2013-11-14  00:00:00   Active     AZ
```

I am trying to get the record that corresponds to the expire date `2013/10/24`. My goal is to show the moment the current status (active - bottom row) started. The correct return would be `2013/10/24` as that is when the corporation was updated from a status 'closed' to a status 'active'.

**The answer is (I think)**

```
select top 1 Y.* from
  (
  select RecordUpdateDate, Status, ExpireDate,
    dense_rank() over (order by RecordUpdateDate desc) as rank
  from [dbo].[Table_1]
  ) X
inner join
  (
  select RecordUpdateDate, Status, ExpireDate,
    dense_rank() over (order by RecordUpdateDate desc) as rank
  from [dbo].[Table_1]
  ) Y
on X.rank = Y.rank- 1  where X.Status <> Y.Status
```

Your answers were key!

Comment: The status field has no procedure associated with it.  It could be anything.  Thank you, it's looking good - But, I have to work from the column/row that has a date 12/31/9999 and whatever status it has - I have to move backwards and get the most recent moment it came into that status.

Comment: for example:  WHERE Status = 'Closed'
  ...  I cant really use that as a filter because the entire corporation could have been active the entire time or the value could be 'in transition' the entire time... or any combination of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query. It joins 2 identical subqueries where I used `dense_rank()` to get the order of record updates and then I get the record where the status changed in the join condition:

```
select Y.* from
  (
  select RecordUpdateDate, Status, ExpireDate,
    dense_rank() over (order by RecordUpdateDate) as rank
  from table1
  ) X
inner join
  (
  select RecordUpdateDate, Status, ExpireDate,
    dense_rank() over (order by RecordUpdateDate) as rank
  from table1
  ) Y
on X.rank = Y.rank - 1 and X.Status = 'Closed' and Y.Status = 'Active'
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a16b0/7)

Answer (score 1):

This should work on any SQL Server version:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t1.* FROM t t1
JOIN (
  SELECT ExpireDate FROM t
  WHERE Status = 'Closed'
) t2 ON t1.ExpireDate >= t2.ExpireDate and t1.Status != 'Closed'
ORDER BY t1.ExpireDate
```

If you are wondering why there is a second check for the `Closed` and why the `ExpireDate` is compared using `>=` instead of `>` is because this is checking for the `Closed` status to happen have the same `ExpireDate` as the immediately `Active` record after it.

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53dd2/1). I've added an extra record in the fiddle with the same date as the `Closed` one to check this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me start by saying that Szymon's solution is definitely the answer to the question you've made, so it's up to you to mark it as an answer. But, I wanted to express that there are better ways to achieve this from an architectural point of view, the only thing is that it would require you to update your database schema to include a log table which makes it easier to query "events" that has happened in relation to a "company".

Basically, that query from Szymon could get extremely slow if you have a lot of data and little resources in your server. However, if you keep a company log that records every status change and any other thing you want to record, it'd be extremely easy and quick to query this log table without the need for so many joins and sub-queries